# Ruby on Rails query string not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3 and am having trouble inserting a query string into a link.

I have a table of posts, and each post has comments. On the posts index page I have each comment with a link to  "reply" to the comment.  I want to insert a query string in the link to "reply"... but it isn't working.  The line I am using looks like this.

```
<%= link_to 'Reply', comment.post, :reply => "@"+comment.commenter+":" if !viewing_post? %>
```

This links to show the post and comment form just fine, but the query string never makes it into the url.  Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't understand the question. More precisely, I don't understand how you expect the reply to look like

Comment: The point of this link is for the url to look like ".../posts/1?reply=@commenter:"    

This doesn't happen, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: `comment.post` is a valid url? and are you sure of your `!viewing_post` condition?

Answer (score 3):

it does not work because link_to is not responsible for the url. link_to only manages the  tag. You need to specify the parameters in the url, you can create urls/paths with parameters by using named routes:

create a named route in your routes.rb like:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments 
end
```

then you can add parameters like:

```
<%= 
    link_to 
        'Reply', 
         post_comment_path(
             comment.post,
             comment, 
             :reply => !viewing_post? ? "@"+comment.commenter+":" : nil
         )
%>
```

this will result in:

```
<a href="comments/:comment_id/posts/:post_id?reply=@whatever_commenter_is:">Reply</a>
```

more infos at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Simon

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  I had the route setup, I just was confused on how to put the reply string in there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `comment.post` is a resource from which a path can be derived, this way you cannot pass any additional GetData  - so in order to append a query string to your url you would have to do the following:

`<%= link_to "whatever",some_real_path(resource,:reply => "@dude7331")%>`